# Getting Object not extensible error while create ChatHeader elements

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

We are integrating LWC in an angular 4 application. We could see chat button but on click of when chatheader and other elements are getting created, I see following exception.

TypeError: Cannot add property configurable, object is not extensible
at m (main.41d0ed6eeb8a174bc7e4.bundle.js:formatted:42348)
at Object.defineProperty (main.41d0ed6eeb8a174bc7e4.bundle.js:formatted:42313)
at new Nn (aura_prod.js:formatted:3621)
at new n (baseChatHeader.js:1)
at new u (chatHeader.js:1)
at aura_prod.js:formatted:4741
at na (aura_prod.js:formatted:4753)
at Sa (aura_prod.js:formatted:4929)
at aura_prod.js:formatted:5464
at new n (aura_prod.js:formatted:4197)
at Object.e.createElement (aura_prod.js:formatted:5463)

I suspect it is because of strict mode. Can anyone please suggest me what could be wrong?

Comment: I think you are trying to update the immutable object, you need to deep clone it.

Comment: this is not my code, this from lwc js files